# Can I change the display driver setting from command line, or something similar?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display, 16.10

Long story short, my GPU (GT 540M) is busted in some way or another, and is now preventing me from running Ubuntu.

I'd noticed that my laptop was using the iGPU for some reason, and installed Nvidia proprietary drivers to remedy this. Switched from the X.Org one to the Nvidia drivers and rebooted.
Now when I boot, I get severe graphical artefacts which don't even let me get past the log in screen.

Can I change it back to the integrated graphics from the boot screen or something?

Running Ubuntu 16.10, in dual boot with Windows 10

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS. Probably the driver does not load.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from nVidia graphics to Intel Graphics is a common solution.

At the login screen use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to bring up console. Now Login with your user ID and password and then use:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo prime-switch intel
sudo service lightdm start
```

Intel driver should now be loaded. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to bring up regular login screen.